# get only digit from scraping data

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Hi i want to get only digit from this data
Result : USD 49000
i want : 49000

```
  from selenium import webdriver
import re
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import selenium as se
options = se.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = se.webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get("https://cex.io/")
data = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/main/section[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]')
print(data.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

If USD is the only option you can use `.replace()` to replace all `spaces` and `USD` with nothing.

The code:

```
data = data.text.replace('USD', '').replace(' ', '')
```

You can also use the next approach if you can have any string and only want the digits:

```
data = data.text
data = [int(x) for x in data.split() if x.isdigit()]
data = ''.join(data)
```

I never did a speed test but if I'm not mistaking `replace` is faster so if you only have the keyword `USD` you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the occurrences of digits in your string you can do this

```py
import re
string = '145fef12r3f3f2'
digits = [digit for digit in re.findall(r'[0-9]*', string) if digit != '']
print(digits)
```

The result is

```
['145', '12', '3', '3', '2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do `data[4:]`to delete first 3 charchters wich is I think a very fast solution without testing it.
You could also use filter combined with isdigit() as @Dead sec said before. Filter is a function wich takes another function and an iterable and delete all element that the functions return false to:

```
print(''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(),data)))
```